# Difference between two ways pushing a value into array state in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I need to know the best way for adding a value to an array, and the difference between these two snippets of code.

```js
setOtoValue((current) => [
  ...current,
  Buffer.from(arraybuf, 'binary').toString('base64')
])
```

```js
setegcValue([
  ...egcvalue,
  ...a.data.content.split(',').map(i => Number(i))
])
```

Comment: Using the first one you are guaranteed that the current state is up to date. In the second - not.

Comment: The second example is wrong. If you place this inside of a `useEffect`, you will have an infinite loop. You should always use the function form of "setValue" when modifying the state. Only use the second form if you are outright replacing the existing state, without referencing the current state "value". Example: [**_II. Infinite loop in useEffect_**](https://alexsidorenko.com/blog/react-infinite-loop#ii-infinite-loop-in-useeffect)

Answer (score 0):

The second example is incorrectly modifying state.

If you place the second snippet of code inside of a `useEffect`, you will have an infinite loop. You should always use the function form of "setValue" when modifying the state. Only use the second form if you are outright replacing the existing state; without referencing the current state "value".

Example: [***II. Infinite loop in useEffect***](https://alexsidorenko.com/blog/react-infinite-loop#ii-infinite-loop-in-useeffect)

**Note:** I'm not sure why your two snippets are setting different states and using different dependencies.

### Correct

Function callback form of "setValue".

```
const [otoValue, setOtoValue] = useState([]);

const addItem = useCallback(() => {
    setOtoValue((current) => [
      ...current,
      Buffer.from(arrayBuf, 'binary').toString('base64')
    ]);
}, [arrayBuf]);
```

### Incorrect

This will cause in infinite loop, because the state for `egcValue` is being set here  i.e. `setEgcValue`, and its dependent i.e. egcValue changing will cause the callback to be infinitely re-computed when it is called.

```
const [egcValue, setEgcValue] = useState([]);

const addItem = useCallback(() => {
    setEgcValue([
      ...egcValue,
      ...a.data.content.split(',').map(i => Number(i))
    ]);
}, [a.data.content, egcValue]);
```

Comment: In the case of a `useCallback`, it won't cause an infinite loop since the setter isn't called right away. It could have an unwanted side-effect of triggering one or more additional renders though. `useEffect` would cause an infinite loop if its logic is improperly gated.